# What is the fastest way to convert Parquet to regular TXT file?

Tags: javascript, python, module, parquet

I was looking into converting really fast from parquet file format to TXT.

Tried with `parquet-tools cat parque_file > parque_file.txt` 
but it takes 2+ seconds for 5KB file.

I believe there is overhead with this tool. What can be the faster way?

(looking under 500ms solution if possible)..

Comment: Why the javascript tag?

Comment: I am using Javascript for a project but not necessarily need to be JS if there is a work-around..

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Python with pandas and pyarrow:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('input.parquet')
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)             # Exporting to CSV is easy
df.to_csv('out.txt', index=False, sep=' ')    # Text is just a tad more difficult
df.to_csv('out.txt', index=False, sep='\t')   # Alternatively, you can use tab separators
df.to_json('out.json')                        # Exporting to JSON is easy as well
```

See the related API docs:

- [pandas.read_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

You can also change the code above to use fastparquet instead of pyarrow and test whether that gives you better or worse performance. All you have to modify is the line that reads the parquet file:

```
df = pd.read_parquet('input.parquet', engine = 'fastparquet')
```

Don't forget to install pandas, pyarrow and fastparquet first by issuing `pip install pandas pyarrow fastparquet` (or similar, depending on your package management solution).